# Use PayPal Payment Button in ASP.NET MVC with ability to get responses about payment status

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am looking for a quick and easy way to integrate PayPal in my website.
So far, I have searched many hours and also found tremendous information about it. (Most of them are out of date).
I know there are many options to go, but it also makes me confused about which way I should choose.

Now, what I want is that :

1. There is only one product on my website and the price depends on hours.
   Say 1 hour for $15, when users select how many hours they want to stay, the Total Price will also need to be updated automatically.
2. I want to use PayPay Payment Button, because I think it's the simplest way to go(if its abilities meet my requirement above)

But in the generated JavaScript for that button:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=myID"
            data-button="buynow"
            data-name="AP Farm Visit"
            data-amount="1"
            data-currency="AUD"
            data-shipping="0"
            data-tax="0.1"
            data-callback="https://apf.azurewebsites.net/Event/PayPal"
            data-env="sandbox">
        </script>

        <a href="javascript:close()">Cancel</a>
```

Now questions:

1. How to change the value for data-amount field. (I think it could be done by JavaScript?)
2. How to write the back-end method `public ActionResult PayPal(FormCollection form)` to get PayPal's responses
3. What fields does the PayPal response have?
4. What do I need to set up in the PayPal's Profile under Selling Tools?